# Combine All Array Inside of Arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem on combining arrays that I wanted to get that's coming from another array.

**datas**

```
   datas = [
      {
        "id": "22333",
        "name": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 1
          },
          {
            "value": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "4444",
        "name": "",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 99
          },
          {
            "value": 66
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

**expected output**

```
final = [
    {
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "value": 2
    },
    {
        "value": 99
    },
    {
        "value": 66
    }
  ]
```

**Code**

```
  datas.map((data) => ({ ...data.details}))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with  [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

> The `flatMap` method returns a new array formed by applying a given callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening the result by one level. It is identical to a `map` followed by a [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) of depth 1, but slightly more efficient than calling those two methods separately.

```js
const datas=[{id:"22333",name:"",details:[{value:1},{value:2}]},{id:"4444",name:"",details:[{value:99},{value:66}]}];
    
const flattened = datas.flatMap(obj => obj.details);

console.log(flattened);
```

To get the actual numbers `map` over the `details` array.

```js
const datas=[{id:"22333",name:"",details:[{value:1},{value:2}]},{id:"4444",name:"",details:[{value:99},{value:66}]}];
    
const flattened = datas.flatMap(obj => {
  return obj.details.map(el => el.value);
});

console.log(flattened);
```

Comment: How about getting the value only?
Like `[2, 99, 66]`.  I did `const flattened = datas.flatMap(obj => obj.details.value);` but it got undefined.

Comment: See the updated answer @Joseph

Answer (score 1):

```js
datas.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return acc.concat(val.details)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `reduce` here:

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push(...curr.details);
  return acc;
}, [])
```

```js
const arr = (datas = [
  {
    id: "22333",
    name: "",
    details: [
      {
        value: 1,
      },
      {
        value: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "4444",
    name: "",
    details: [
      {
        value: 99,
      },
      {
        value: 66,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push(...curr.details);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```